# MySQL - How can I remove characters from string if it's longer than a certain amount?

Tags: mysql, database

How can I remove all trailing characters from my meta key `rapportnummer` if the string is longer than 6 characters.

If my string is `12345678` I'd want it to automatically remove `78`

Previously I've used this short query to remove every `/` from that same field:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '/', '') WHERE meta_key = 'rapportnummer';
```

Is what I'm asking possible to achieve in MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT(value, 6)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTR` regardless of length of the string as follows

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = SUBSTR(meta_value,1,6) WHERE meta_key = 'rapportnummer';
```

Answer (score 0):

Google https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MySQL+-+How+can+I+remove+characters+from+string+if+it%27s+longer+than+a+certain+amount&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=rI3HVK5Ry_VQr_2CyAs and the answer is underneath this post, on Google.

here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

And from this:

```
LEFT(str,len)
```

> Returns the leftmost len characters from the string str, or NULL if any argument is NULL.
>
> mysql> SELECT LEFT('foobarbar', 5);
>           -> 'fooba'
>
> This function is multibyte safe.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I do see your point and have added a bit about `LEFT` and how to use it in an SQL query. Part of the reasoning for my answer was to point out that searching a search engine can give the results required, probably quicker than writing on SO and awaiting a response.

Comment: Martin, I appreciate you linking the appropriate documentation :) The reason I decided to post a question here is because I don't have any experience with MySQL and am naturally very nervous to use documentation sources when I have no experience with the language. I somehow feel a lot safer when given human feedback on the correct course of action. However, I'll read up on this seeing as I might be using this a lot more (such an incredibly useful language).

Comment: ok, I do see your side of it, perhaps if writing again, angle your question to ask for "what is the best way to..." rather than "how do I..." . And yes, I think the MySQL documentation - while correct - is not that nice to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wep_postmeta
SET meta_value = LEFT(meta_value,6)
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(meta_value)>6
```